# How to queue new jobs when running Spark on DataProc

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

How is it possible to submit several jobs to Google Dataproc (PySpark) and queue the jobs which do not fit on the current executors?

Only submitting jobs does not work for queueing, here the output for any following job:

```
 $ gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark myjob.py
 ...
 WARN  Utils:70 - Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041
```

YARN should take a "queue" parameter for this purpose. However, I cannot find any documentation about using it with dataproc...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case you probably want to just ignore that warning; it's actually just a harmless warning, and your driver is indeed getting properly queued up on that same cluster; ports are simply [bound to successive port numbers starting at 4040](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html) when multiple drivers are running on the same host (the dataproc master). Note that this does *not* mean the later submission actively waits for the first to finish; the job submission tries to run as much concurrently as there are resources for. In Dataproc, if you submit, say, 100 jobs, you should see something like 10 of them (varies depending on machine sizes, cluster sizes, etc) immediately get queued up in YARN, and several (or all) of them will successfully get enough YARN containers to begin running while others remain PENDING in YARN. As they complete, Dataproc will then incrementally submit those remaining 90 jobs to YARN as resources become available.

At the moment there's no specialty support for YARN queues, though it's supported if you want to customize your YARN queues at cluster-creation time using:

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create --properties \
    ^;^yarn:yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.queues=foo,bar,default;spark:other.config=baz
```

(replacing the [gcloud delimiter](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/escaping) with `;` to pass through the comma-separated list) and/or additional `yarn-site.xml` configs as outlined in tutorials like [this one](https://support.pivotal.io/hc/en-us/articles/201623853-How-to-configure-queues-using-YARN-capacity-scheduler-xml), and then you specify the queue with:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark --properties spark.yarn.queue=foo
```

though that won't change what you see about the port 4040 warning. This is because the default setting is to use `yarn-client` mode for Spark, meaning the driver program runs on the master node, and driver submission is not subject to YARN queuing.

You can use `yarn-cluster` mode as follows:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark --properties \
    spark.master=yarn-cluster,spark.yarn.queue=foo
```

Then it'll use the `foo` yarn-queue if you've defined it, as well as using `yarn-cluster` mode so that the driver program runs in a YARN container. In this case you'd no longer hit any port 4040 warnings, but in `yarn-cluster` mode you also don't get to see the `stdout/stderr` of your driver program in the Dataproc UI anymore.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations. Would you mind to update the documentation of dataproc at some point in future? ;-)

Comment: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#configuring-pool-properties - I think I will try your suggestion together with the pool configuration general to YARN. Should work, though?!

Comment: It works now as described by yourself. Thank you very much. Is there a way to get jobId from dataproc inside the SparkContext / running job? I would like to save results in reference to ApplicationId and JobId to cover both the YARN and dataproc context.

Comment: Can you correct your commands? Acc. to $: gcloud topic escaping this works: `--properties ^-^yarn:yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.queues=import,batch,default` and is necessary to parse the list of queues.

Comment: Fixed, used `;` and added a second example property to illustrate the delimiter replacement.

Comment: Great documentation! Thanks!

Comment: Friendly reminder that the YARN Queues configuration goes in the `capacity-scheduler.xml` file which requires the `capacity-scheduler:` `file_prefix` in the properties.